# Paris transit visa

Tags: visas, transit, layovers, paris, transit-visas

I am travelling to Algeria (ALG) via Air France, and I need to change flights at the airport in Paris. My stay in the airport is not more than 2 hours both ways.
I also have a valid US visa.

Do I need a Paris transit visa? If yes, do I need to get 2 visas for coming and return?

My flight is Bombay–Algeria–Bombay by Air France with 2 hours flight change in Paris.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a visa for airside transit in Paris thanks to your US visa. Assuming you are an Indian citizen, you would otherwise need an airport transit visa (ATV). If you would need an ATV, you could use a single visa provided it's valid on both dates.

See [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-in-the-schengen-area) for more details.